# How to work with array of maps in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary

I've got a problem with initialize an arrays of map objects in my typescript interface like below:

```
interface SomeInterface{
    id: string,
    types: Array<Map<string, number>>;
}
```

I need to create object with field types as an array which will be hold many of map with string and number. I want this, but i don't know how to add new map into this array.

I try even in this way but it not work and `types` is still an empty object:

```
const t: Array<Map<string, number>> = new Array<Map<string, number>>();
const map = new Map<string, number>();

t.push(map.set("test1", 2));
t.push(map.set("test2", 5));

const a: SomeInterface= {
    id: "test",
    types: t
}

console.log(a); 
//{
//  "id": "test",
//  "types": [
//    {},
//    {}
//  ]
//}
```

Can someone tell me how to add new map into an typescript array?

thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure you really want `types` to be an **array** of string->number maps? Can you provide an example of the multiple maps you'd have in one of those arrays?

Comment: The `Map`s looking like empty objects `{}` I think is just an artifact of the typescript playground. If you look in the chrome console and expand the object they're filled with your 2 values (You're adding the same map twice to the array though!)

Comment: You pushed the same map twice into the array; it's *not* an "empty object", but depending on your console log functionality it might show up as one (if it does a `JSON.stringify()` to serialize it, for instance.  Do [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wk5PlN) and you'll see what's in there.)  But it's not clear what you're really trying to achieve or how you intend to use it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code I would do something like following

```
const t: Array<Map<string, number>> = new Array<Map<string, number>>();


t.push(new Map([["test1", 2]]));
t.push(new Map([["test12", 5]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example showing how you can:

- create an array of maps
- create a new map
- set items in the map
- push the map into the array

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=17&ssc=47&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAngeQGYFk4AcIBcMAgkqgDw67nQICWYA5gDQxgCuAtgEYCmCAPgEwAvDADaAXQDcAWABQCgPRKYwBLzhRe8GJzwLQkWPtwBGUW14B3GFRpR6TVhx78BACgCUcxfJXwACaBMLxgjnS8EDBQIDEAFjqmCqZmAHQQvFAeAETa0GY5rGY+KXjpmdl5UVAATEUwtaV+AQyZCLBQiXp48J3dYSEgGAk6iMgoCuOomFQQabjsEPEeqc2G4BAgADa8adsgjB7T6Nh4ED4wAeJUMB5NMADe1QU5osJmrC91byLCtQBfSQKDbGGAYOgIaBUACSYFIE0sJ1m53EAAYZKCtrt9ocPBCoVBYfCyChLgFbvcvE9voV3jBPjBvvV6YCsTs9gcjgToXg4QjUKIRGI1tIrqpHOxeAogA)

```ts
const arrayOfMaps: Array<Map<string, number>> = [];

// create a map
const map1 = new Map<string, number>();

// add entries to the map
map1.set("test1", 1);
map1.set("test2", 2);

// insert the map at the end of the array
arrayOfMaps.push(map1);

console.log(arrayOfMaps); // [Map (2) {"test1" => 1, "test2" => 2}]

const firstMapInArray = arrayOfMaps[0];
console.log(firstMapInArray); // Map (2) {"test1" => 1, "test2" => 2}
console.log(firstMapInArray === map1); // true
```